# Oxygen font with uneven S char when font size: 12px

Tags: css, fonts, font-size, glyph

I'm trying to use the `Oxygen` font on a website with size: `12px`.

This is the font:

https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Oxygen?preview.text=THIS%20IS%20A%20TEXT%20WITH%20UNEVEN%20S%20CHARS%20ON%20%22Regular%20400%22&preview.text_type=custom

**My problem is:** when using size: `12px` the `S` char is uneven as you can see below:

[image]

Is there any way to make the S char even with size: `12px`?

Thanks!

Comment: I have no code for you, but to prevent this from happening you will need to JS search each textline for the use of an 'S' and replace that with a smaller one like a `a textline with  a <span class="inline-S">s</span>pecial class`, which sucks. Or do it manually in the HTML.
btw, I checked with other fonts, same issue. Must be some internal rounding error in browsers => font metrics vs. pixel unit. Better ignore it, saves you the trouble.